# error: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found

Tags: mongodb, openssl, rhel7

I am getting the error when I run command "mongo" in linux client on RHEL 7.2:

```
/usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by mongo)
```

I have already installed openssl 1.0.2:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: How did you configure OpenSSL, and how did you configure Mongo? I believe you need to configure both with *both* RPATHs and the new tags. Also see [Issue 3993, libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3993) in the OpenSSL issue tracker. Its sad Linux still has not fixed the broken path problem after 30 years or so.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by running `yum reinstall openssl openssl-libs` and `yum reinstall libzip`

Answer (score 0):

```
error: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found
```

Above error is showing user have two library for same tool that's why system not able to decide which is/are the right file/files.
Delete one of them (system defined : under /usr/lib or user defined : path defined by user) and try it.